# How to undo the changes made through developer options in dom using angular 4?

Tags: angular, dom

I have an input element which is binded through [(ngModel)]  and with [disabled] directive. A form is used to submit the changes. If disabled is true then element is disabled, but using developer options any one can change dom by removing disabled. How to retain and submit old value?

Comment: why do worry about making changes through dev options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, the code is available to anyone, so there is no way to ensure it will not be changed (even if you retain the old value as you mentioned, this could also be changed).

So, you shall provide this kind of functionality in your web app to enhance user experience (for example disabling buttons to avoid invalid form submission), but you must always validate the data on the server side to make sure it is valid.